# Highlighting row with jQuery on checkbox select

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, html-table

I have tried to highlight the row in a table using jQuery when the checkbox is checked. Used this jQuery code for the same.

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

I'm getting it correct for only alternate rows. I have used the following CSS to style the alternate rows in the table.

```
.tables tbody tr:nth-child(2n){
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
}
```

How can I highlight the even rows too?

Comment: Could you include the `<table></table>` markup here?

Comment: You can check that in the link above!

Comment: Right, but if your page goes down then this question won't be as useful anymore `:-/`

Comment: But the table code is very large. It includes a lot of other markups.

Comment: anddd 3 years later, the page is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this style to your css file

```
.tables tr.highlight td {
  background-color: #FFF9DC;
}
```

The problem is that your even rows styles overrides highlight style. So all you should do is to make your highlight style more important.

Comment: One more question. I have another checkbox in the same row. When I click in that checkbox also, the row is highlighting (which is not needed). How do I trigger the jQuery only for the first checkbox?

Comment: Add some class to checkboxes you want to behave in this way. And bind jQuery with something like this `$(".some-class:checkbox").change(function()...`

Comment: May be try like this

$(".A input:checkbox").change(function()

Where A is a class for the checkbox!